# Doubt on constructor structure

Tags: solidity

Suppose there is a 3 contracts:

```
contract A {
    uint num;
    constructor(uint num){
        num=num;
    }
}
```

```
contract B is A {
    string name;
    constructor(string memory _name, uint num)A(num){
        name = _name;
    }
}
```

```
contract C is B {
    address me;
     
     < constructor >
}
```

As we can see contract-C is inherits from contract-B which also inherits from contract-A, in this case how the constructor of contract-C will be structured?
Will it be structured like this?

```
constructor(address _me, string memory _name, uint _num)B(_name)A(_num);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be

```
contract C is B {
    address me;
     
     constructor(address _me, string memory _name, uint _num)B(_name,_num);
}
```

Contract C, only has to instantiate only B.

Hope it helps!

Comment: What is this process called? instantiation of contructor?

Comment: And tell me one thing, ERC721URIStorage.sol from OZ also inherits from ERC721 but did not instantiate constructor, why? 
https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol